# Viewing recent network connections on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

I recently discovered an excessively large cellular data usage spike on my iPhone at a time when I was definitely not using the network (let alone the phone itself). During the conversation with my service provider about what they could do about it (a positive result, thankfully), I asked if they kept logs of the IP addresses visited from my phone. They said they did not.

It got me thinking though:

Is there any iOS developer-accessible log on iOS that documents network history (i.e. TCP/UDP packets sent or maybe `NSURLSessions` opened, destination addresses, etc)? And if so, how can I access it? Note: I'm only after legitimate non-jailbroken methods. That being said, if there was a way to access this sort of information after a `dd` of the phone (or something similar), I wouldn't mind knowing about it!

(I have seen a few iOS packet-sniffing questions on SO, but these all deal with real-time sniffing, not history or logging.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a security point of view, if Apple had a public API allowing developers to access network traffic logs across the whole system then this would cause a privacy issue.

For that reason, I don't think there is anything you can do legitimately (without jailbreaking)... Well not that I have seen anyway.

**Side Note:** In iOS 8, you will be able to block specific apps from using mobile data from the Settings app.